# How to fix 403 (Forbidden) error when posting data from Javascript to Django

Tags: javascript, django

```
var upload = function(files) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
            files: files
        },
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: 'files/',    
    });   
}
```

I try to send files to Django but I am getting this error.

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/upload/files/ 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Try change `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}'` for `csrfmiddlewaretoken: jQuery('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()`

Answer (score 3):

you put the token in the header before you send it with ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{csrf_token}}');
    },
    data: {"files":files},
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: 'files/',    
    });
```